# Tracking Redirects in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

We have purchased a couple of URLs that basically just redirect to our main page. Is there a way to track the webpage redirects?
I looked at the page at [Google Analytics](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1009614?hl=en). and it doesn;t really say, in a practical way what to do.
I also read a post that says to place an index.html on each dummy URL with the Google analytics code. Does this mean that I need to get a new account for the new page?
I'm kind of lost, here

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the type of redirect.  If it's a 301, you should be able to see the data in the 'All Referrals' report under the Acquisition section.

If it's a 302, then you may need to do some more work.  I wouldn't recommend the index.html route. Instead you may want to work with your IT staff to place in a parameter in the redirect rule so that instead of domainX.com redirecting to domainY.com/, it instead redirects to domainY.com/?src=domainX.com

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is a 301 redirect, but all our sites are hosted outside our company, how do i get the  domainY.com/?src=domainX.com changed

Comment: I don't think you need to on a 301.  Do you see any data in Google Analytics under the referrers report?

Comment: Nope there's no reference to the redirected websites at all.

Comment: Hmm.  Could you post a link to the site?  Or local at the HTTP traffic when you visit one of the redirected domains?  I would be curious to see what the HTTP referrer is.

Comment: the redirected(dummy) site is www.ItsAboutYourSpecs.com. The root page is www.PioneerMetal.com